# Use of multiple regression for data on 20 countries representing nearly the whole population

Tags: multiple-regression, population

I have operational expenditure data for 20 countries (representing 90% of the whole population) which I want to compare with other variables from the countries (e.g. GDP, Population etc). Do I still need to worry about the P-value/t-stats or can I just focus on the coefficients and the R square value of my (linear) regression. How many different variables could I include given the number of observations? Thanks